# Open and close browser tab in android browser via intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I know I can open a URL in a new tab in a browser from an android app using an intent.

But is there a good way to also close such a tab that my app has opened before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, sorry. There is no standard `Intent` structure for this. While it is possible that some browsers offer something, I am not aware of any that do.

Bear in mind that there is no requirement that your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` open up a browser *tab*, as the user's chosen browser may not offer any sort of tab UI metaphor.

Comment: but some of applications are doing that. e.g Avast antivirus close current tab of firefox when suspecious url is detected.

Comment: @NaumanAsh: They are not using an `Intent` for that, most likely.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve that. I am unable to find any solution so far.

Comment: @NaumanAsh: I hope that you need a partnership with the Web browser developers. It would be very disturbing if any app could go in and attack a Web browser this way.