# Close browser tab from application

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Like a parental control application, I have bloacked few websites. As the blocked url is detected its re-directed to about:blank.
Evey thing is working fine, problem arises in Android 4.4 Chrome browser.
about:blank opens in new tab, along with recentaly open tabs.
I want the close all thoes tab. Below is what i have done.

```
Intent mBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mBrowserIntent.setPackage(packageName);
mBrowserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                                     
mBrowserIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID , packageName);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(defaultURL);
mBrowserIntent.setData(uri);                                
startActivity(mBrowserIntent);
```

Comment: Apparently there isn't an easy way to do this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712779/open-and-close-browser-tab-in-android-browser-via-intent

Comment: Alright, but its random. Sometime only new single tab is opened, next time all recently visitied website and tab are opened along with it. I cant undestand this behaviour. Already done   Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
           Browser.deleteFromHistory(getContentResolver(), url);