# How do I close all android chrome tabs through adb?

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb

I want to visit a site grab some data. close the chrome app. visit next site and repeat. However when I kill chrome using -

```
adb shell am force-stop com.android.chrome
```

and restart it next time, it remembers everything from previous session and opens those tabs too. How do stop chrome from doing that through adb ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open and close browser tab in android browser via intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712779/open-and-close-browser-tab-in-android-browser-via-intent)